# Both Webmin & ISPConfig won't work on my Ubuntu Linode

Tags: webmin

I followed the steps on [this page](http://library.linode.com/web-applications/control-panels/webmin/installing-webmin) to download and setup Webmin on my Linode Ubuntu server, however, when I try to visit https + my.ip.add.ress + :10000, the page just hangs and nothing loads. I already looked into my firewall settings.

I uninstalled Webmin and installed ISPConfig and all its dependencies, and the same thing happens at https + my.ip.add.ress + :8080.

This is my first time managing a server so there could be something I overlooked. But my server is a pretty vanilla Ubuntu 12.10 with LAMP stack installed exactly as per the instructions in Linode's documentation.

Comment: does it work with http?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get ISPConfig 3 deployed, by following these instructions: [The Perfect Server - Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (nginx, BIND, Dovecot, ISPConfig 3)](http://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-ubuntu-12.04-lts-nginx-bind-dovecot-ispconfig-3)

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question it's better to copy the salient parts into your answer so that, if in the future  the link is no longer active, the details remain.

Answer (score 0):

Did you perhaps setup a firewall? if so, be sure to add an exception to the firewall.rules to allow sniffing on port 10000